# Table in DIV stick together when drag&drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Day,
I have an empty DIV `<div id="DragDropZone"></div>` in which I generate 2 tables side by side dynamically. These tables can be dragged and dropped in a series of many.
When I add my tables to the DOM, I do this:

```
var dvTable = document.getElementById("DragDropZone");
dvTable.appendChild(table1);
dvTable.appendChild(table2);
```

I would like to have the second table sticked to the first, when it's dragged and dropped, so I can move both at once.
Anybody has an idea ? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: How about putting table1&table2 in table 3 and make table3 dragable?

Comment: That's an idea. I was also thinking about the snap property in jQuery-ui...

Comment: Good thinking, I guess you can go either way, What i would do is something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46589029/6434747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var dvTable = document.getElementById("DragDropZone");
var parent = document.createElement("table");
parent.classList.add('draggable');

parent.appendChild(table1);
parent.appendChild(table2);
dvTable.appendChild(parent);
```

Comment: Precisely! Thanks!!